# PACS integration manually

Tags: mirth, dcm4che, cornerstonejs, dicomweb, orthanc-server

I am currently working on a healthtech website that uses ai to detect abnormalities in scans and so far the website works on manual upload of scans. I wanted to eliminate manual upload by pulling the study list out of the pacs server which can then be processed for the ai model. I am currently working with the MEVN stack and I have a cornerstone dicom viewer that integrated into my website and was wondering if I can get any help with this pacs integration. Any help is appreciated.